# How to access Joomla Admin form field values?

Tags: php, joomla

I have been searching for accessing Joomla form field values from admin side and also have found some links but these links couldn't help me.

```
    <field name="fields" type="hidden" default="ZAIN" />
```

Here I want to access its value and want to modify its value after accessing. 

**Here is full Form in xml format**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <form name = 'learning_jform'>
        <fieldset>
            <field name="id" type="hidden" />
            <field name="fields" type="hidden" default="ZAIN" />
            <field
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    label="Enter Name:"
                    description="COM_FORMMANAGER_FORMMANAGER_NAME_DESC"
                    size="40"
                    class="inputbox"
                    default=""
                    />
        </fieldset>
        <field name="types" type="list" default="" label="Select Field Types:" description="">
            <option value="text">text</option>
            <option value="email">email</option>
            <option value="password">password</option>
            <option value="textarea">textarea</option>
        </field>
    </form>
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do here, and where. Do you want to set the value before displaying in a backend form ? Or before saving ? etc...

Comment: @JulienV I want to access form values and need to modify form values after accessing

Comment: i answered in your other post...

Answer (score 0):

Where are you wanting to access the field?  In a module?  In general, try:

```
$myField = $params->get('fields', 'ZAIN');
```

Comment: I want it in MVC Component model and it is giving error `Call to a member function get() on null` and why should I need to enter its default value? what If I want to set its field value?